# How to let typescript know about submodule path aliases

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have the following use-case:

I have a `module A` it's a typescript project with webpack, a next.js app. I have path aliases setup in this module.

Then, I have `module B`, this is also a typescript project, there is NO webpack for this module, nor is it a nextjs poject, it just contains typescript files and a `tsconfig.json` with path aliases.

`module A` can import files from `module B` because module B is an npm workspace. So in `module A` I have codes which import from B like

```
import { Button } from '@scope/moduleB/button';
```

`module A`'s build system is supposed to transpile the imported files.

This is working, the problem arise, when the imported file from `module B` uses a path alias.
I get errors from next's `info  - Checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.` step that it can't resolve the path alias when traversing the imported file.

Is there any solution to this?

I tried to find solutions to this problem but each of my search results were referring to how we can introduce type aliases for a certain application and not on how typescript could know about imported module's path aliases.